# ST_Intersect on polygons PostGIS : argument of JOIN/ON must be type boolean, not type record

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, postgis

I am using this code in PostGIS to inner join two polygons files.

My tables:

```
table p : vietnamgis.vnm_adm3

ID geom        ADM1       .... ....
1  01600000..   tan bin
2  01600000..   san 
3  01600000..   dan


Table b : vietnamgis.cadastrewfg

gid  geom        description  ... ...
1    01600000..   house
2    01600000..   commercial
3    01600000..   house
```

My code

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS public.overlap;
CREATE TABLE public.overlap AS
SELECT b.geom As bgeom, p.geom As pgeom, 
         ST_Intersection(b.geom, p.geom) As intersect_bp
    FROM vietnamgis.cadastrewfg b INNER JOIN vietnamgis.vnm_adm3 p ON (b,p)
    WHERE ST_Overlaps(b.geom, p.geom)
    LIMIT 1;
```

I did create before `CREATE EXTENSION postgis;`

```
SELECT PostGIS_Version();
3.0 USE_GEOS=1 USE_PROJ=1 USE_STATS=1
```

```
ERROR:  argument of JOIN/ON must be type boolean, not type record
LINE 5: ...mgis.cadastrewfg b INNER JOIN vietnamgis.vnm_adm3 p ON (b,p)
                                                              ^
```

What is wrong here, how can I fix to join my polygons files?

Comment: Where have you seen `ON (b,p)` used as a join condition before?

Comment: https://www.bostongis.com/postgis_intersection_intersects.snippet

Comment: That example uses `ST_Intersects(a.the_geom, b.the_geom)` not `(a.the_geom, b.the_geom)`

Answer (score 2):

Your join  clause seems wrong: instead of the table aliases (`b` and `p`) you should compare the related keys columns, for example:

```
FROM vietnamgis.cadastrewfg b 
INNER JOIN vietnamgis.vnm_adm3 p ON b.you_b_col_ley = p.you_p_col_key
```